# Creating a Javafx image from a int array

Tags: javafx, pixel, pixelformat

I am desperately trying to create an Image from a pixel-array with integer values. Regardless of using the WritableImage or the Canvas, it is always said that the PixelFormat is BYTE_RGB or BYTE_BGRA_PRE, so that I am forced to use a byte-array.

Is there any way to change the PixelFormat to `<IntBuffer>` or did I overlook another component that is capable of having a `PixelFormat<IntBuffer>`?

Answer (score 6):

You haven't described the structure of the pixel data in your `int[]`, but you can do something along the lines of

```
int[] pixels = ... ;
WritableImage img = new WritableImage(width, height);
PixelWriter pw = img.getPixelWriter();
pw.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(), pixels, 0, width);
```

Comment: Thank you very much four answer! Using PixelWriters setPixels()-method seem not work for me properly. The image doesn't appear! My ImageView only loads it when changing to byte[] pixelarray and byte-PixelFormat it shows up.Also         
System.out.println(img.getPixelWriter().getPixelFormat().getType());
spids out „BYTE_BGRA_PRE“

Comment: What is actually in your array of ints?

Comment: Well... what are you actually expecting to see then? If all the pixels have zero alpha, they are all transparent.